# Is there a way to have two "music" folders in my iTunes library?

Tags: itunes, music, libraries

I want to have two music folders in my iTunes library. I want to separate some of my songs to one library and the others to the second one, so i can be more organized.

Is there a way to do that ?

I am already aware of the possibility to have two itunes libraries but that requires resetting the software and doesn't really provide a comfortable solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can organize an iTunes library by using playlists and folders of playlists.

Using two libraries is not that complex. You just have to hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> key while launching iTunes and it will ask you which library you want to open. Alternatively, you can double click a library for launching iTunes on that library.